# replace a string with a neighbour string

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have a file on my Linux machine with multiple lines with this structure:

s    **name.scaffold** start size direction length sequence

I need to change it to be

s    **scaffold.scaffold** start size direction length sequence

for example, change from:

```
s       Sapo.scaffold_1  19037   10      +       13588361        ATAATAAAAT
s       Rana.RANA1        9000   10      +       13588361        ATAATAAAAT
s       Sapo.scaffold_5  19037   10      +       13588361        ATAATAAAAT
s       Sapo.scaffold_8  19037   10      +       13588361        ATAATAAAAT
s       Coqu.SGBE0296.1  68900   10      +       13588361        ATAATAAAAT
```

to:

```
s       scaffold_1.scaffold_1  19037   10      +       13588361        ATAATAAAAT
s       RANA1.RANA1             9000   10      +       13588361        ATAATAAAAT
s       scaffold_5.scaffold_5  19037   10      +       13588361        ATAATAAAAT
s       scaffold_8.scaffold_8  19037   10      +       13588361        ATAATAAAAT
s       SGBE0296.1.SGBE0296.1  68900   10      +       13588361        ATAATAAAAT
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
sed 's/[[:alnum:]]*\.\([[:alnum:]_.]*\)/\1.\1/' file
```

This looks for a string that starts with set of alphanumerical characters followed by a dot.  This part of the line will be deleted. After these, there should be a string consisting of alphanumerical characters, dots or  underscores.  This is all replaced by that second part of the expression, twice, with a dot in-between.

Given your data in the question, this produces

```
s       scaffold_1.scaffold_1   19037   10      +       13588361        ATAATAAAAT
s       RANA1.RANA1     9000    10      +       13588361        ATAATAAAAT
s       scaffold_5.scaffold_5   19037   10      +       13588361        ATAATAAAAT
s       scaffold_8.scaffold_8   19037   10      +       13588361        ATAATAAAAT
s       SGBE0296.1.SGBE0296.1   68900   10      +       13588361        ATAATAAAAT
```

This assumes that a "name" is matched by `[[:alnum:]]*`, and that a "scaffold" is matched by `[[:alnum:]_.]*`.

A slightly more "pedantic" regular expression would be

```
sed 's/[[:alnum:]]\{1,\}\.\([[:alnum:]]\{1,\}\([._][[:digit:]]\{1,\}\)\{0,1\}\)/\1.\1/' file
```

where none of the substrings on either side of the dot is allowed to be empty, and where the scaffold suffix (`_1` or `.1` etc.) is matched optionally and separately from the scaffold name.

As an extended regular expression (which may be easier to read), this would be written as

```
sed -E 's/[[:alnum:]]+\.([[:alnum:]]+([._][[:digit:]]+)?)/\1.\1/' file
```

For the given data, this produces identical output to the first command.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{
    sub(/[^.]*\./,"",$2) #From the 2nd field, remove all up to first dot
    $2=$2"."$2           #Replicate the resulting second field
    print
}' file | column -t
```

Output:

```
s  scaffold_1.scaffold_1  19037  10  +  13588361  ATAATAAAAT
s  RANA1.RANA1            9000   10  +  13588361  ATAATAAAAT
s  scaffold_5.scaffold_5  19037  10  +  13588361  ATAATAAAAT
s  scaffold_8.scaffold_8  19037  10  +  13588361  ATAATAAAAT
s  SGBE0296.1.SGBE0296.1  68900  10  +  13588361  ATAATAAAAT
```

Comment: the fifth line of sample input data has 2 dots ...

Comment: @AlexStragies I think it is all right now, thank you for calling my attention to that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
awk -F '\t' '{$2=gensub(/\w+\.(.*)/,"\\1.\\1","g",$2);}1' file | column -t

s  scaffold_1.scaffold_1  19037  10  +  13588361  ATAATAAAAT
s  RANA1.RANA1            9000   10  +  13588361  ATAATAAAAT
s  scaffold_5.scaffold_5  19037  10  +  13588361  ATAATAAAAT
s  scaffold_8.scaffold_8  19037  10  +  13588361  ATAATAAAAT
s  SGBE0296.1.SGBE0296.1  68900  10  +  13588361  ATAATAAAAT
```